# Getopt::Declare vs Getopt::Long

Tags: perl

My company uses [`Getopt::Declare`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Efangly/Getopt-Declare-1.14/lib/Getopt/Declare.pm) as its command line option parser. The structure of our option processing blocks routinely look like this:

```
Readonly my $ARGS => Getopt::Declare->new(
   join( "\n",
      "[strict]",
      "--engineacct <num:i>\tEngineaccount [required]",
      "--outfile <outfile:of>\tOutput file [required]",
      "--clicks <N:i>\tselect keywords with more than N clicks [required]",
      "--infile <infile:if>\tInput file [required]",
      "--pretend\tThis option not yet implemented. "
         . "If specified, the script will not execute.",
      "[ mutex: --clicks --infile ]",
   )
) || exit(1);
```

that's a lot to look at... I tried to make it a little simpler by using HEREDOCS like most of the documentation uses:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all'; 

use Readonly; 

Readonly my $ARGS => Getopt::Declare->new(<<'EOPARAM');
  [strict]
  --client <client:i> client number [required] 
  --clicks <clicks:i> click threshold (must be > 5)
EOPARAM
```

While I think this is much easier to read, for some reason it won't recognize any of my arguments.

```
perl test.pl --client 5 --clicks 2
```

I get unrecognized arguments:

```
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--client')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('154')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--clicks')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('2')
```

So I guess I have two quesitons:

1. Has anyone successfully used HEREDOCS with *Getopt::Declare*?
2. Is *Getopt::Declare* still a reasonable option for an option parser? As opposed to other modules like *Getopt::Long*

Comment: Getopt::Declare and Getopt::Long tend to be the most heavily used; I'd say either is a viable choice, depending on preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original version, your string consists of `--clicks <N:i>` followed by a tab, followed by `select keywords with more than N clicks [required]`.

In your revised version, your string has space instead of a tab.

Use `<<"EOPARAM"` and "`\t`" instead of `<<'EOPARAM'` and "".

```
>type x.pl
use Getopt::Declare;
Getopt::Declare->new(<<'EOPARAM');
  [strict]
  --client <client:i> client number [required]
  --clicks <clicks:i> click threshold (must be > 5)
EOPARAM

>perl x.pl --client 5 --clicks 2
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--client')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('5')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--clicks')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('2')

(try 'x.pl -help' for more information)
```

```
>type x.pl
use Getopt::Declare;
Getopt::Declare->new(<<'EOPARAM');
  [strict]
  --client <client:i>\tclient number [required]
  --clicks <clicks:i>\tclick threshold (must be > 5)
EOPARAM

>perl x.pl --client 5 --clicks 2
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--client')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('5')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('--clicks')
Error: unrecognizable argument ('2')

(try 'x.pl -help' for more information)
```

```
>type x.pl
use Getopt::Declare;
Getopt::Declare->new(<<"EOPARAM");
  [strict]
  --client <client:i>\tclient number [required]
  --clicks <clicks:i>\tclick threshold (must be > 5)
EOPARAM

>perl x.pl --client 5 --clicks 2

>
```

Comment: They are still unrecognized even with leading spaces removed.

Comment: Yeah, found that out too. Updated.

Comment: I'm confused as to why that tab is required, but thank you for your help.

Comment: In bold text in the docs: "Note that in each of the cases above, there is a tab between each parameter definition and description (even if you can't see it)!"